# Multiple foreign key of the same type in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have `Issue` entity having 2 fields as `FK` to `User` entity as shown below. Although I properly configured the properties in order to prevent creating extra `Xxx_Id` fields instead of `PropertyNameId`, there is a `Xxx_Id` field created in the table besides `PropertyNameId` fields. In this example `User_Id` field is created in the `Issue` table besides `AssigneeId` and `ReporterId` fields. Is there any mistake here? Does `HashSet` in the `User` entity causing this extra `User_Id` field?

**Issue:**

```
public class Issue : BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //Foreign key for Reporter (User entity)
    public short ReporterId { get; set; }

    //Foreign key for Assignee (User entity)
    public short AssigneeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ReporterId")]
    public virtual User Reporter { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AssigneeId")]
    public virtual User Assignee { get; set; }
}
```

**User:**

```
public class User : BaseEntity 
{
    [Key]
    public short Id { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    //code omitted for brevity 

    public User()
    {
        Issues = new HashSet<Issue>();
        //code omitted for brevity 
    }        

    public virtual ICollection<Issue> Issues { get; set; }

    //code omitted for brevity 
}
```

Here are related lines in the migration file:

```
CreateTable(
            "Issue",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    ReporterId = c.Short(nullable: false),
                    AssigneeId = c.Short(nullable: false),
                    User_Id = c.Short() //???
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("com.User", t => t.User_Id)  //???
            .ForeignKey("com.User", t => t.AssigneeId)
            .ForeignKey("com.User", t => t.ReporterId)
            .Index(t => t.ReporterId)
            .Index(t => t.AssigneeId)
            .Index(t => t.User_Id);  //???
```

Comment: Can you post content of `BaseEntity` class?

Comment: Got your problem! I am answering it thoroughly.

Comment: @NguyenThanh I added, thanks...

Comment: @TanvirArjel Thanks a lot, I am waiting for your reply...

Answer (score 1):

As you are trying to create multiple `ForeignKey` of the same type, so
your model classes set up should be as follows:

```
public class User : BaseEntity
{
    public User()
    {
        ReporterIssues = new HashSet<Issue>();
        AssigneeIssues = new HashSet<Issue>();
    }

    [Key]
    public short Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public virtual ICollection<Issue> ReporterIssues { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Issue> AssigneeIssues { get; set; }
}

public class Issue : BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public short ReporterId { get; set; }
    public short AssigneeId { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public virtual User Reporter { get; set; }
    public virtual User Assignee { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the `OnModelCreating` configuration as follows:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(u => u.AssigneeIssues)
            .WithRequired(i => i.Assignee).HasForeignKey(a => a.AssigneeId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false); // <-- cascade delete must be false

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(u => u.ReporterIssues)
            .WithRequired(i => i.Reporter).HasForeignKey(a => a.ReporterId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false); // <-- cascade delete must be false
 }
```

Comment: Many thanks Tanvir. I used [InverseProperty] several years ago and you are right, the problem is using multiple FK of the same type and this seems to solve the problem. Before proceeding: **1)** Can I use [InverseProperty] that you comment out and omit OnModelCreating part? Because I used to [InverseProperty] before like this. Any idea? **2)** If I use OnModelCreating part, there is no need to use the [InverseProperty] part that you comment out, is that true???

Comment: You can omit the `[InverseProperty ]`. but `OnModelCreating` is must as cascade delete has to be turn off. See my updated answer and read the comment to the code.

Comment: I have removed the inverse property from the answer.

Comment: Just being curiosity, Can I use only [InverseProperty] approach instead of OnModelCreating approach and omit OnModelCreating part?

Comment: Read my previous comments here!

Comment: @Willys if it helped you please don't forget to mark it as answer and give a up vote. Thanks.

Comment: Wait a minute pls, I am searching these at the same time and of course will inform you about the result after applying them to my project. I also looked at my previous project where I used [InverseProperty] without OnModelCreating part. In this scene can we say that when using [InverseProperty] without OnModelCreating part, we cannot configure WillCascadeOnDelete and for this reason I should use OnModelCreating approach. Is that true?

Comment: Yes! You are correct! If cascade delete would not be an issue then we could have omit the `OnModelCreating` part. As turning off cascade delete here is must, so we have to use `OnModelCreating` as obligatory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188413/discussion-between-tanvirarjel-and-willys).

Comment: Many thanks for your help, voted up. I tried this approach using [InverseProperty] without OnModelCreating part and managed to solve the problem. Now I have to be clarified about these issues. Could you clarify me pls? For this issue (using ultiple FK on the same entity, using [InverseProperty] without OnModelCreating will solve the problem but CascadeDeleting cannot be set (actually I also tried to delete a record (I did not use OnModelCreating part) and it was not deleted with cascade delete error). Is that completely true?

Comment: `I tried this approach using [InverseProperty] without OnModelCreating part and managed to solve the problem.` - How did you turn off cascade delete problem? Or did not face this problem?

Comment: I know t is impossible to turn off cascade delete in this case. But not sure, maybe setting nullable to the FK fields as int? (ReporterId, AssigneeId), we can achieve this. Is that true? Or what if I set nullable to the FK fields as int? (ReporterId, AssigneeId)?

Comment: Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Comment: @Willys You are making simple thing quite complex and thinking out of box! Just follow my updated answer please!

Comment: Sorry, I just 2 little question and this is last. Could you pls have a look at chat?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I asked my question on chat page. Just to be clarified about the issue, sorry. Thanks a lot for your kind helps...